# C++: function to append file, called within other functions

Tags: c++

So, I am trying to log information about the status of the c++ project code in a text file. The program terminates unexpectedly, so I need to append the file as I go rather than storing info in an array along the way. I wanted to call the function to write to the file from within other functions, eventually in the other c++ files as well.

The code is a huge project that has many files and the "main()" technically exists in a separate file from all of the functions that are called throughout the function of the code (therefore not a useful file for me). My plan was to open the file in the setup() function, and then call the function within other functions along the way. Just in case I did not explain the setup of the code well enough, here is the link to the file I am trying to add to: https://github.com/cstracq2/ardupilot/blob/master/ArduCopter/ArduCopter.cpp

I have seen other notes on what may help, but I am not that familiar with c++ and I don't know what most of it means. From what I saw, **this is one of the ways I tried, and it is failing to compile**.

```
#include "<existing header>.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void log_data( ofstream &datafile, int value);

void <>::function1()
{ ....<stuff that was already there>
    log_data( datafile, <value> );
}

void <>::function2()
{ ....<stuff that was already there>
    log_data( datafile, <value> );
}

void setup()
{ ....<stuff that was already there>
    ofstream datafile;
    datafile.open("data_log_file.txt");
}

void log_data( ofstream &datafile, int value)
{
    data_file << value << endl;
}
```

If there is any advice that you could give me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `void <>::`? That's not a valid syntax. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And if that's your *actual* code then you should probably start over with a beginners book.

Comment: You might also want to read e.g. [this `std::ofstream::open` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) if you want to append to the end of a file.

Comment: I didn't want it to be too confusing. The code is setup in piecemeal. <> is an object called "Copter" in this case, but I didn't want it to be confusing without any explanation of what that is. The functions are not called "function1" or "function2" either, but I wanted to try to show conceptually in an easy way. The code cannot be shown in one excerpt in this post because of the way the project is set up. The file does not directly contain the main function, but rather all of the functions that I want to pull information from.

Comment: Well without information about the errors (when posting questions about build error, please include the complete and unedited output, preferably copy-paste the full build log) or the actual code that generates the errors it's impossible to say anything. That's why it's so important to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), code says more than a thousand pictures.

Comment: Ok I will try, but the last time that I did, The number of "notes" that were returned exceeded the max length of the terminal space and was over 400 lines. I will try to include the error, since is usually says that the datafile I am trying to write to does not exist in the space of the other functions.

Comment: How would you suggest uploading the error messages?

Comment: @ChristinaNStracquodaine You're trying to use a variable local to `setup` in the other functions. A minimal example is `void f() { int x; } void g() { x = 0;}` (you can read more about variable scope in your book). You need some kind of global state.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know that this is an issue, but for the sake of this setup with the file, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would suggest to use the Singleton Pattern. Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
class Logger
{
    std::ifstream logF;
    static Logger *s_instance;
    Logger(std::string &path)
    {
        logF.open(path, std::ios_base::in);
    }
public:
    void log_data(int val)
    {
        logF << val << std::endl;
    }

    static void create_instance(std::string &path)
    {
        s_instance = new Logger(path);
    }
    static Logger *instance()
    {                
        return s_instance;
    }
};
```

Now you can just include the header with the class def and call something like:

```
Logger::instance()->log_data(<value>);
```

And do not forget to init the class before calling the static method (somewhere in main for instance):

```
Logger::create_instance(<path>);
```

Of course, you can just make it easier by hard-coding a value for your path, but if the path changes you'll have to re-compile everything.

Or just use something already implemented like [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you! Is that latter piece of code the exact syntax I would use inside other functions? I have not seen "->" in code yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what this "path" actually is.

Comment: Yes. That "->" shows you that you are accessing the properties/methods of a pointer. Basically, you are creating an instance of your class and to access the properties of the object you just allocated you reference it as a pointer. the instance() method does not return a copy of your object but an address of it.

Comment: @ChristinaNStracquodaine "path" is a string specifying the location of your log file, e.g. "/tmp/mylog.log" in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes now that you mentioned the use of `datafile` in other function I see the error: The variable `datafile` is a *local* variable inside the `setup` function.

It should either be a member variable or possible a global variable.

Comment: I had seen something that said that is why I prototype it with the ampersand. (I'm sure you can tell that I am not familiar enough with this to understand why either one is correct). How would I setup a globally accessible file?

Comment: @ChristinaNStracquodaine When you declare a variable inside a function, it's local inside that function and only exist in that function. No other function can access that variable. The term you should search for and read about is *scope*. To make it a global variable, just declare it outside or any function.

Comment: I just tried FILE * datafile; in with the prototypes and declarations, and used datafile=fopen(...) in setup function, and then used datafile << values << endl in the writer function. It tells me that "endl" is not defined in the scope.

Comment: I changed it to std::endl and that error disappeared, but now is still is giving me: error: invalid operands of types 'FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}' and 'int' to binary 'operator<<' pointing at value in  datafile << value << std::endl

Comment: @ChristinaNStracquodaine `FILE*` is the old C style file handle, you need a C++ *file stream* like your old `datafile` variable. You should just have copied it into the global scope. I.e. use `std::ofstream` instead of `FILE *`.